# How can reverse a part of an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, binaryfiles

I am writing a program that takes a bitmap file to read into memory. But as I am reading it into memory I am making some changes. First I am inverting the colors of the pixels. I managed to get this working. Now I am trying to flip the image on the Y-Axis. I have tried using two for loops but would end up get segmentation faults and also I didn't like how messy it looked. On my second attempt I found a different approach that's cleaner due to it only using one loop and one condition vs 2 loops and 2 conditions. My code now produces no errors but doesn't perform the intended operation. Is there another algorithm I could possibly try?

Below is some code for part of my program. I am trying to reverse the pixel when I am reading them row by row.

```
    fseek(fin, bfh.offset, SEEK_SET);

    Pixel *p = new Pixel[bih.height * bih.width];

    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < bih.height; i++) {

        for (uint32_t j = 0; j < bih.width; j++) {

            uint32_t index = i * bih.width + j;

            fread(&p[index], 1, sizeof(p[0]), fin);

            p[index].blue = 255 - p[index].blue;
            p[index].green = 255 - p[index].green;
            p[index].red = 255 - p[index].red;

        }

        uint32_t k = (bih.width * i) - 1;
        uint32_t c = 0 + (i * bih.width);

        if ( i == 0) {
            k = bih.width - 1;
        }

        while( c < k) 
        {
            temp = p[c];
            p[c] = p[k];
            p[k] = temp;
            c++;
            k--;

        }

        fseek(fin, padding_bytes, SEEK_CUR);

    }

    fclose(fin);
```

Below is my whole program if needed.

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdio>

#pragma pack(push, 2)
struct BitmapFileHeader {

    uint16_t type;
    uint32_t size;
    uint16_t reserved_1;
    uint16_t reserved_2;
    uint32_t offset;

};
struct BitmapInfoHeader {

    uint32_t size;
    uint32_t width;
    uint32_t height;
    uint16_t planes;
    uint16_t bitcount;
    uint32_t compression;
    uint32_t imagesize;
    uint32_t x_pixels_per_meter;
    uint32_t y_pixels_per_meter;
    uint32_t color_used;
    uint32_t color_important;
};
#pragma pack(pop)

struct Pixel {
    uint8_t blue;
    uint8_t green;
    uint8_t red;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if(argc != 3) {
        printf("Usage : %s input_file output_file\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    FILE *fin;
    FILE *fout;
    BitmapFileHeader bfh;
    BitmapInfoHeader bih;

    Pixel temp;

    fin = fopen(argv[1], "rb");

    if (nullptr == fin) {
        perror(argv[1]);
        return -1;
    }

    if (sizeof(BitmapFileHeader) != fread(
        &bfh,
        1,
        sizeof(bfh),
        fin
    )) {
        printf("Unable to read bitmap file header. \n");
        return -2;
    }

    if (sizeof(BitmapInfoHeader) != fread(
        &bih,
        1,
        sizeof(bih),
        fin
    )) {
        printf("Unable to read bitmap info header. \n");
        return -3;
    }

    printf("Size of File Header = %lu\n", sizeof(BitmapFileHeader));

    int8_t first = (bfh.type >> 8) & 0xff;
    int8_t second = bfh.type & 0xff;

    if ( (first != 'M') && (second != 'B') ){
        printf("Input file is not a Bitmap file. \n");
        return -4;
    }

    printf("File type = %c%c\n", first, second);
    printf("File size = %u\n", bfh.size);
    printf("File offset = %u\n", bfh.offset);
    printf("File width = %u\n", bih.width);
    printf("Info size = %u\n", bih.size);

    uint32_t padding_bytes = 0;
    uint32_t row_bytes_final = bih.width * sizeof(Pixel);
    uint32_t row_bytes_initial = row_bytes_final;

    do{
        uint32_t rem = row_bytes_final % 4;

        if (rem != 0) {
            row_bytes_final += 1;
        }

        padding_bytes = row_bytes_final - row_bytes_initial;

    } while( (row_bytes_final % 4) != 0);


    fseek(fin, bfh.offset, SEEK_SET);

    Pixel *p = new Pixel[bih.height * bih.width];

    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < bih.height; i++) {

        for (uint32_t j = 0; j < bih.width; j++) {

            uint32_t index = i * bih.width + j;

            fread(&p[index], 1, sizeof(p[0]), fin);

            p[index].blue = 255 - p[index].blue;
            p[index].green = 255 - p[index].green;
            p[index].red = 255 - p[index].red;

        }

        uint32_t k = (bih.width * i) - 1;
        uint32_t c = 0 + (i * bih.width);

        if ( i == 0) {
            k = bih.width - 1;
        }

        while( (c * bih.width) < (k * bih.width)) 
        {
            temp = p[c];
            p[c] = p[k];
            p[k] = temp;
            c++;
            k--;

        }

        fseek(fin, padding_bytes, SEEK_CUR);

    }

    fclose(fin);


    fout = fopen(argv[2], "wb");

    if(nullptr == fout) {
        perror(argv[2]);
        return -5;
    }

    if( sizeof(BitmapFileHeader) != fwrite(
    &bfh, 
    1, 
    sizeof(bfh), 
    fout
    )) {
        printf("Unable to write bitmap file header.\n");
        return -6;
    }

    if( sizeof(BitmapInfoHeader) != fwrite(
        &bih, 
        1, 
        sizeof(bih), 
        fout
        )) {
            printf("Unable to write bitmap info header.\n");
            return -7;
        }

    fseek(fout, bfh.offset, SEEK_SET);

    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < bih.height; i++) {

        for (uint32_t j = 0; j  < bih.width; j++) {

            uint32_t index = i * bih.width + j;

            fwrite(&p[index], 1, sizeof(p[0]), fout);

        }

        fseek(fout, padding_bytes, SEEK_CUR);


    }

    if (padding_bytes > 0) {
        fseek(fout, -1, SEEK_CUR);
        fputc('\0', fout);
    }


    fclose(fout);
    delete[] p;

    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got the bounds wrong, it should be `c = i * bih.width; k = (i + 1) * bih.width - 1;`.

You can also use [`std::reverse`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse) to do this:

```cpp
std::reverse(p + i * bih.width, p + (i + 1) * bih.width);  // Exclusive end, so no -1
```